# Move around an Ubuntu installation without losing its booting ability?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, grub

I have a multiboot laptop. I need to re-arange its partitions in order to eficientizice HDD usage.
I found out that when I move my Ubuntu 14.04 installation it loses the ability to boot. After googling an investigating for a while, I detected that Grub2, its bootloader, makes reference to a specific sector on the disk, which of course changes when I move the partition to another place on the disk.

How can I find the new "specific sector" and how do I reconfig Grub2 so it points to this?

More info:
Grub is entirely installed in the Ubuntu partition "sda1", it doesn't touch the MBR ("sda") in any way (I use Ranish to manage the MBR, and want to keep it that way. Reinstalling Ubuntu is not an option or I wouldn't be asking here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you able to open GParted, such as from an Ubuntu LiveCD?

Answer (score 0):

There are directions for reinstalling the grub2 bootloader at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing:
"The user may wish to reinstall GRUB 2 for a variety of reasons...
When using the grub-install command, the boot information is updated and written to the designated drive, missing - but not corrupted or intentionally deleted - files are restored. Specifically the core.img, grubenv, and device.map are updated and missing modules restored. If missing, the grub folder will be recreated. The grub-install command does not generate a new GRUB 2 menu (grub.cfg)." Hope this is acceptable, if complete reinstallation is not.